# How to "Update Model From Database" programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I started with an EF 6 Database First using an EDMX file for two specific columns.

The project is a website which is deployed once each month.

If I make some changes in these columns(from the database), I just execute the "Update Model From Database..." command and its fine.

My question is...

Is there a way to check programatically in the global.asax if the database has changed, and then update the mappings for these columns automatically?

Answer (score 2):

It's a difficult and long way to go where you'll need to update the store schema (SSDL), but doable. Here's good resource that will help you start

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2013/08/30/entity-framework-schema-redirection.aspx